# Cannot sync my HTC8 with Windows 10

Tags: drivers

I have an issue since upgrading to Windows 10 from W7.

I used to access my phone's files through File Explorer, connected via USB cable, but now when I connect my HTC M8 (Android), I am informed the `USB device is not recognized.`

In device manager, it is shown as

> Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)'

And inside the properties, it shows :

> Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)

This indicates one of many things such as

- A power issue (the USB not getting power), gut it's a 800 watt PSU with only 2 hard drives, 1 GPU and 2 PCI-E so I don't believe power is any problem
- A driver issue, but I've ensured my chipset driver is up to date
- The 'sync' software is update to date (as this apparently comes with the drivers)
- The fault is shown because the device is stopped responding

When I try to update driver, Windows informs me I already have the best driver

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is due to a faulty USB port on the phone.

The reason for this is since posting, I charged my phone and it fizzed and bizzed (electrical noises) followed by a burning smell.

Whilst the phone still can charge, it is not detected by any PC I've tried (W10, W8 or W7) using different cables. This suggest the fault is not PC side.